# Room database.withTransaction { } block not Resolved

Tags: android, android-room, remote-mediator

I am following [this tutorial](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041134648/en) about RemoteMediator and everything is fine until I run into a weird error when using `database.withTransaction{}` to allow database operations.

[image]

Unfortunately, the IDE doesn't seem (or is refusing) to recognize this very genuine and
legit block. I have checked that I  defined ROOM Database abstract class correctly and declared these ROOM and Paging 3 libs in build.gradle(app) file.

```
    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"

    // Room-paging artifact
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.3'

    // Paging 3.0
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha16'
```

So I decided to ignore the error and went ahead to call a `dao` function inside the `withTransaction{}` block but I get **Suspension functions can be called only within a coroutine body**.

This is a bit confusing since RemoteMediator's `load()` override function is already a **suspend function**.

Anyone with insights on this issue please help as I don't seem to be getting anywhere around this.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `room-runtime` dependency and not `room-runtime-ktx` if you want the Kotlin extensions of Room?

Comment: I used `room-runtime` because it was the first one that popped up on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room). Surprisingly, when I switch to `androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3` the `db.withTransaction{}` block is now resolved!! Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [@ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) day-saving comment above, if you run into this situation just change the ***room-runtime*** flavor from:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
```

to ***room-ktx*** flavor:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
```

As per [Developers Docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) ktx-libs provide Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support which is exactly what `database.withTransaction{}` block is - it is an extension function on RoomDatabase as shown on this line from the source code.

```
public suspend fun <R> RoomDatabase.withTransaction(block: suspend () -> R): R {
```

> Android KTX is a set of Kotlin extensions that are included with
> Android Jetpack and other Android libraries. KTX extensions provide
> concise, idiomatic Kotlin to Jetpack, Android platform, and other
> APIs. To do so, these extensions leverage several Kotlin language
> features, including the following:
>
> - Extension functions
> - Extension properties
> - Lambdas
> - Named parameters
> - Parameter default values
> - Coroutines